# 'Reference to uninitialized composite' while trying to execute a stored procedure in Oracle with UDTs

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, package, user-defined-types

There is this package and I am trying to execute using the code below. However I get an error

> ORA-06530: Reference to uninitialized composite

Code:

```
DECLARE
   StudyNum    InputTyp := InputTyp ();
   StudyDetails   OutputTyp := OutputTyp ();
BEGIN
   StudyNum.EXTEND;
   StudyNum (1) := '9071';
   my_package.my_procedure(StudyNum, StudyDetails);
END;
/
```

The package is created as below with user-defined datatypes as input & output params:

```
Create OR REPLACE Type InputTyp  AS VARRAY(200) OF VARCHAR2 (1000);
CREATE  TYPE OBJTYP AS OBJECT
(
    A            NUMBER,
    B             VARCHAR2 (1000),       
    C        VARCHAR2 (100)       
);
CREATE TYPE OutputTyp IS VARRAY (2000) OF   OBJTYP;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE my_package
AS
    PROCEDURE my_procedure(p_StudyNum IN InputTyp,p_StdyDtl OUT OutputTyp);
END my_package;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY my_package
AS
   PROCEDURE my_procedure(p_StudyNum IN InputTyp,p_StdyDtl OUT OutputTyp)
IS
    i            BINARY_INTEGER := 1;
    j            BINARY_INTEGER := 1;
   CURSOR c_StudyTbl
   IS
     SELECT A,  B, C
     FROM my_table
     WHERE Study_Number = p_StudyNum(i);

  v_StudyTbl   OBJTYP;
BEGIN
    p_StdyDtl := OutputTyp ();
    LOOP
 --  This is the first cursor opened for each of the items in the list.
  EXIT WHEN i > p_StudyNum.count;

 OPEN c_StudyTbl;
 LOOP

    FETCH c_StudyTbl INTO v_StudyTbl;
    EXIT WHEN c_StudyTbl%NOTFOUND;

    p_StdyDtl.EXTEND ();
    p_StdyDtl (j).A := v_StudyTbl.A;
    p_StdyDtl (j).B := v_StudyTbl.B;
    p_StdyDtl (j).C := v_StudyTbl.C;
    j := j + 1;
 END LOOP;
 CLOSE c_StudyTbl;
i := i + 1;
END LOOP;

IF c_StudyTbl%ISOPEN
THEN
   CLOSE c_StudyTbl;
END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
THEN
   NULL;
END;
END my_package;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

you would either need to do :

```
p_StdyDtl(p_StdyDtl.last) := OBJTYP(null, null, null);
p_StdyDtl (j).A := v_StudyTbl.A;
p_StdyDtl (j).B := v_StudyTbl.B;
p_StdyDtl (j).C := v_StudyTbl.C;
```

or simpler:

```
p_StdyDtl(j) := OBJTYP(v_StudyTbl.A, v_StudyTbl.B, v_StudyTbl.C);
```

your code as-is fails because you've initialised the `OutputTyp` but not the `objtyp` part.

but as I said in the [prior question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503720/pls-00386-type-mismatch-found-between-fetch-cursor-and-into-variables), the `multiset` avoids all of that.

Comment: Yes, the multiset approach gets rid off the problems - thank you ! Really appreciate these inputs @DazzaL